# Creating New Release and got 'Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key'

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, sha1

## Hi

So while publishing a new version of my App on the Play Store, I got an error which says that I have a new SHA1 fingerprint compared to the last release. So I realized my mistake and found that while making the **.aab** file using the **expo build:android -t app-bundle** command I pressed the *Generate New Keystore* button, now I am not able to fix it. Please someone help me.

> This is the error

```
Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is
signed with the correct signing key and try again. Your app bundle is expected to be
signed with the certificate with fingerprint:

SHA1: CD:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:A7

but the certificate used to sign the app bundle that you uploaded has fingerprint:

SHA1: 0D:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:8A
```

> The screenshot of the error

[image: play.google.com]

> Here is my app.json code

[image: VS Code Window.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keystore may be versioned if it was committed as part of your project so simply reverting that change would restore the previous keystore for you to use.

Alternatively, you'd need to contact Google and go through the process of establishing your new keystore as the valid signing entity. You can reach out to Google via [this form](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/key)

You'll need to provide a certificate from your new keystore which you can generate with the following command:

```
keytool -export -rfc -alias prod -file upload_certificate.pem -keystore keystore.jks
```

Comment: Thanks, but I found that I can change the version of the app and use EAS build to build and deploy the app to Play Store.